# Where's my Windows gone!

Tags: windows

I installed ubuntu on my xp computer but when it starts up it just boots strait into ubuntu & I can't access xp at all.Where's it gone?
 I think I might have made a mistake not setting up a partition beforehand.I just moved the slider allocating 79gb to abuntu & leaving windows with 71gb assuming that was making a partition that I could duel boot from.Now I'd like to remove abuntu & start again but how do I do it?

Comment: Which options you choose exactly when you installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had this before but I might be able to help. When your computer turns on there should be a place where it says a button you can press in order to boot your computer on a different drive (I think it might be F11) maybe when you do that you will have the option to revert to your previous operating system.

Comment: Sadly no joy :-(